# WordPress.com to WordPress.org migration: How to download the wp-content folder?

Tags: wordpress, migration

Lets assume the official WordPress Import/Export Plugin does not work on every host as well as on localhost. Lets assume it is possible to import the posts, but not the media. Lets assume WordPress.com does not offer a free possibility to download all the media from their site.

http://example.com/ is currently hosted on WordPress.com

Tons of uploaded images are hosted like this:

https://example.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/1.png
https://example.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/1.png
and so on....

Possibility 1: Is there a Tool which can download all the images hosted on the blog while preserving the folder structure (I did not find one yet).

Possibility 2: Is there a possibility to download all media (especially images) from WordPress.com with the XML export files, but without the official WordPress Importer Tool (without having to write a custom parser for the XML-files).

With a simple search/replace on the database one could replace the host in the database and upload the extracted images. A better solution is welcome, too.

Comment: Are you allowed to `<?php passthru("tar cfz - wp-content/");`?

Comment: As far as i know any custom code is prohibited on wordpress.com :-P

Comment: The official solution is "use the WordPress Importer" but for most people it just doesnt work, its also rated very badly :-/

Comment: Hm. Can you at least download a database dump? In that case you can set up a localhost copy (only update wp_options 'siteurl' and 'home'), and get the URLs for all the media posts (post_type `attachment`). You can make a little PHP script to query those posts and download the images one by one.

Comment: The only thing i can get are xml-files containing the media urls. I could write a parser and download em with a script one by one but i wondered if there is an easier possibility :-P

Comment: That's good enough. It may be though, that not all media files are listed, only those attached to posts. Do you have root on a Linux or Cygwin machine?

Comment: What would it be good for too have root on a linux/cygwin machine? I could setup one within a virtual machine.

Comment: The available tools. I would have suggested a commandline oneliner to download all the images. But, I see you're up for a little scripting; shouldn't take more than 3 lines of PHP. When it comes to wordpress, that's often how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this with the following script. This may be helpful for everybody having the same problem:

(index.php)

```
<?php include('functions.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          Choose the XML export file from WordPress.com (one-by-one). Execute the script with the same file until you see "success":<br> 
            <input name="myfile" type="file" size="50" accept="text/*"> 
          </p>  
          <button type="submit">... go download em all!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

(functions.php)

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && ($_FILES['myfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
    // $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']); 

    $filestr = file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    $matches = null;
    $returnValue = preg_match_all('/https:\\/\\/mydomain.files.wordpress.com\\/[0-9]{4}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[^<>\\/]+(\\.jpg|.png|.gif|.jpeg|.bmp)/',$filestr,$matches);



    foreach($matches[0] as $image_url) {
        $rep = str_replace("https://mydomin.files.wordpress.com",'',$image_url);
        $save_path = "/images".$rep;

        // if not image already downloaded
        if(!file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).$save_path)) {
            $img_only = strrchr($save_path,"/");
            $path = dirname(__FILE__).str_replace($img_only,"",$save_path);
            if(!is_dir($path)) {
                mkdir($path, 0777,true);
            }
            file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).$save_path, fopen($image_url, 'r'));
        }
    }
    // if not reached, repeat the script
    echo "success";

}
```